# Managing calls between carrier number and Google Voice, using GV as primary

Tags: google-voice, call-screening, voicemail

I'm looking for the best way to set-up/manage my calls between the carrier # and Google Voice as I use both.

I'm using a Samsung S4 on VZW *(however I would prefer to use phone/Google Voice/app to manage rather than rely on VZW settings)*

I have certain calls go to Google Voice and the rest go to carrier. The problem is that the 'other' calls are many and I was sick of hearing my phone ring all day when I only want to receive those calls at specified times. Part of my solution was figuring out how to set-up call blocking on the S4 *(last phone was a Thunderbolt and as far as I knew this wasn't in the settings)*

My big problem now is that every blocked call ends up going to my Voice-mail and a lot of them have automated recordings so my inbox is filling up. I'd like to find a way to block all carrier calls, and not allow them to forward to my Google Voice inbox for Voice-mail on a specified schedule.

e.g. Block all calls/VM's M-F 1am-1pm

Answer (score 0):

If the "other"  calls are usually at certain times of the day, you could use Tasker to automate things for you.

Comment: Do you have the recipe for this?

Comment: I may be able to figure one out for you, but I'd need the specifics of what you're trying to do, and when... On a side note, I've only used Tasker a handful of times, and I'm not, currently, running it on my phone. I'm willing to give it a shot, though.